# Get dictionary value by iterating through values on a list | Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want make a function `search_subject` to search for a subject and find the respective professor of the subject e.g `{professor1 : [biology, maths],  professor2 : [gymnastics, arts]` If you enter `biology` when you are asked for input you get `professor1`

I'm trying to avoid making a nested dictionary for this project and I'm stuck, any help is appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please provide some python-like data sample and code you've already written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through `professors.items()` and check for the subject

```py
professors = {'professor1' : ['biology', 'maths'],  'professor2' : ['gymnastics', 'arts']}

def search_subject(target):
    for key, val in professors.items():
        if target in val:
            return key
    return False

print(search_subject('biology'))
```

Output: `professor1`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to quote the strings.
Invert the dictionary.
Use the inverted dictionary to look up professors by subject.

```
professor_to_subjects = {'professor1' : ['biology', 'maths'],
                         'professor2' : ['gymnastics', 'arts'], }

subject_to_professor = {}

for professor, subjects in professor_to_subjects.items():
    for subject in subjects:
        subject_to_professor[subject] = professor

print(subject_to_professor)
# {'biology': 'professor1', 'maths': 'professor1', 'gymnastics': 'professor2', 'arts': 'professor2'}

print(subject_to_professor['biology'])
# professor1
```

Comment: And maybe don't answer questions you've [_already identified_ as problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634915/get-dictionary-value-by-iterating-through-values-on-a-list-python/72634987#comment128304453_72634915).